# In mongoDb, how to get the entire record if a string input matches any array element (an array is a property of the records in this case)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Consider following record in db:

```
{
 name:"potato",
 age:"404",
 hobbies: ["brains", "zombieesss", "eat guitar"]
},

{
 name:"tom",
 age:"4",
 hobbies: ["guitar", "cooking", "soccer"]
}
```

What I want to achieve:

1. if a certain input is "guitar", both records must show.
2. if the input is "soccer" the second record must show.
3. input can also be ["cooking", "soccer"] for which the second record must show.

I have thought of:-

Get the "hobbies" of all records then pass each of the arrays to a function that would give me the required records but it seems like the worst way to do it.

Comment: would that work? because in this case hobbies is an array? also, I am using mongodb.

Comment: you have to filter the data in database before returning them to node.js to avoid unecessary network transfer

Comment: It should work...  `db.DBNAME.find( { hobbies: { $exists: true, $in: [ "brains" ] } } )`

Comment: @AlainIb I am seeking help for the same. Once the database has more records it will be a waste to filter the entire result set.

Comment: Please provide reasons for the downvotes so that I may ask better questions next time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). Try the following queries:

```
db.collection.find( { hobbies: {$regex: "(.*guitar.*)"} } )

db.collection.find( { hobbies: {$regex: "(.*cooking.*)|(.*soccer.*)"} } )
```

".*" in regex query means match zero or more occurrences of any character

For your input you can create regex query with such code:

```
var input = ["cooking", "soccer"];
var regex = input.map(function(item){ return "(.*" + item + ".*)" }).join('|');
db.collection.find( { hobbies: {$regex: regex} } )
```

Comment: I'll try this once and I am pretty sure that I'll be marking this as the answer. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Say you form an array from your database table (though exaclty I don't know how you storing it), then

```js
function filterEl(arr, what){

   return arr.filter(function(el){
     
        return el.hobbies.join(",").indexOf(what) != -1;
      
     });

}

var x = [{
 name:"potato",
 age:"404",
 hobbies: ["brains", "zombieesss", "eat guitar"]
},

{
 name:"tom",
 age:"4",
 hobbies: ["guitar", "cooking", "soccer"]
}];
 
console.log(filterEl(x, "guitar")); // will return 2 elements
console.log(filterEl(x, "soccer")); // will return the last element.
```

Comment: This was on my mind, but how would that fare if the number of records were to increase? doing a `db.collection("random").find()` and then filtering the cursors.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still not so clear to me but what i understood is if the input (about hobbies) present in the input array,then print the hobies.

Here i will store the hobies in a variable if it matches.

let say input:

```
var a="guitar"

$.each(myObj,function(k,v){

    if(v.hobies.indexOf(a) > -1){
       // string present in an array you may proceed here...
}
});
```

Hope this answer may help you

Comment: My question is, how to get the entire record if a string input matches any array element of all the records even partially.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
db.collection.find( { hobbies:{$or:[{/.*guitar.*/},{"cooking"},{"soccer"}]} })
```